# System.Data.Sqlconnection

Tags: asp.net

in my application when i type sqlconnection it is not showing any intellisence, i added the namespace System.Data.Sqlclient not only sqlconnection even i am not getting Page calss can u help me.
actually i am sharing this application from my company server.

in our company previously there was .net 2.0 frame work when this project was developed(one year back).
yesterday our company installed 3.0 .net frame work is this any problem for previous project which are developed in 2.0 how can i go through this problem

Comment: Is there a problem of intellisense for only SqlConnection or others as well?

Comment: other also even i am not getting any Process like that

Comment: sqladapter,datareader like ...

Comment: What I meant was for example, if you include System.IO, are you able to get "File" class on intellisense?

Comment: no iam not getting any thing even i am not able to type System.Io.
i just edit my question can u read once pleace thank you for response

Comment: Have you already tried the options listed in my answer?

Comment: hmm..It didnt work still? Which version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: 2005 vs and 2.0 .netframework

Comment: Those options worked for VS 2008 at least. I edited my answer again. Could you please check?

Comment: Were you able to get this problem resolved?

Comment: ya i installed .net framework 2.0 i have to check it whether it is working or not Mr. Ashish Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if your intellisense works at all first. You can try :-

1) Start your visual studio using the following :-

devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

2) Go to Tools > Option > Text Editor > All Languages . Make sure all the checkbox related to "Statement Completion" are "checked" (not just filled).

3) Close Visual Studio, delete the .suo (user option file) which is located at teh same directory as your solution file. Note that that file might be hidden. Open Visual Studio again and check for intellisense.

**EDIT :- To see the hidden .suo file (or any other hidden files), follow below steps:-**

1.Open My Computer.

2.From the Tools menu, choose Folder Options....

3.Click on the View tab in the Folder Options window.

4.In the Advanced settings: text area, locate the Hidden files and folders category.

Note: The Hidden files and folders category should be viewable at the bottom of the Advanced settings: text area without scrolling down. You'll see two options under the folder.

5.Choose the Show hidden files and folders radio button under the Hidden files and folders category.

6.Click OK at the bottom of the Folder Options window.

Comment: if you don't mind can u read my question i just edit my question

Comment: i didn't find .suo file how can find it

Comment: ya Mr.Ashish Gupta i got the solution i installed framework 2.0 in my server and place the project in that server then share from the server it is working  now